# App can't deploy on iPhone show "ApplicationVerificationFailed: Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement."

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin.Forms on Visual Studio (Windows Machine) not able to deploy the app on iPhone and shows the error like "ApplicationVerificationFailed: Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement." and solution is build successfully problem only with deploying.

Comment: try to delete existing app in your iPhone.

Comment: Tried with deleting existing app but issue is present

Comment: @PavanRaghamwar Having a check that Certificate whether be right. Right click ios project -> Choose Properties - > IOS Bundle Signing - > Automatic Provisioning ,checking whether can work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/?tabs=windows